# What's the logic of default permissions of /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts?

Tags: security, ssh, permissions

By default, Debian and Ubuntu (at least) set `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` without read permission for others. What's the logic behind that? I can't think of any security risks with `o+r`, and, on the other hand, having it publicly readable is useful for admin-distributed files.

Comment: ... and RHEL / CentOS 7. but not RHEL9

Comment: This appears to be a relatively safe way to manage the file, assuming that none of your hosts are compromised: 
`
ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa,ed25519  newhost1 newhost2 newhost3  | sort -u - /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts  | install -m 0644 /dev/stdin  /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
`
If  one of these hosts was already in the ssh_known_hosts file and you add it on the command-line, you will have a duplicate which may or may not trigger an error. Perform at own risk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that the point of blocking access to that file is to prevent a intruder who has compromised your system from getting a list of hosts that your system my have access to.  The similar logic applies to the `HashKnownHosts` option being enabled by default lately.  You generally don't want your system to provide everything an intruder needs to get control of everything on your network.

If you only added hashed entries into your `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` I don't think it would really be as big of a deal since reversing the hash is not possible.

Comment: No, the file does not work if it is not world readable.

Comment: I think you're probably correct.  It's a bit like cutting off the head to save the nose.  The result is that every user must depend on their own fingerprint authentication process, rather than allowing a centralised mechanism. Making it read-only means the file's utility is incredibly limited (to the root user, who shouldn't be using ssh). As with most security things, it's a tradeoff between one possible weakness and another

Answer (score 1):

If this still happens then it seems to be a bug. ssh uses the users permission when it reads this file, so if it is not world readable then it has no effect at all.

I just tested id. 
If I set the permission of /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts to 600 then ssh displays that "The authenticity of host ... can't be established."

If I set it to 644, than I can login in to the remote server without the prompt.

sshd [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8) clearly states that "This file should be writable only by root/the owner and should be world-readable."

Answer (score 0):

ssh keys should not be shared without good reason.  /etc/ssh/* are configuration options that apply to *all* users.  The ssh_known_hosts file is a way to specify a list of known hosts for all users that log into that box.  I believe you can also add entries to /home/*/.ssh/known_hosts to apply a "known" host to a specific user.  There should be no problems with the owner having read permissions.... in fact... all users should have read-permissions on that file.  The concern is when you apply write permissions.

That file is used to identify the remote server's fingerprint... so when you ssh into your uber-secure server... you're actually ssh'ing into your server...and not some other server owned by a hacker that is playing man-in-the-middle.